# For loop not recognizing writeLAS command

Tags: r, lidar, lidr, for-loop

I am currently trying to run a `for` loop in R that creates las files from a vector of 530 objects (`EABplots`). I have downloaded `lidR`, `rLiDAR`, and the relevant packages that come along with them (`sp`, `raster`, etc.), but it still isn't allowing me to run my `for` loop.

My code:

```
plots <- seq(1:530)
for(n in 1:length(plots))
{
  plot.n <- plots[n]
  writeLAS(EABplots[[plot.n]], filename = paste(plot.n, ".las",  sep = ""))
}
```

Error Message:

```
  Error in writeLAS(EABplots[[plot.n]], filename = paste(plot.n, ".las",  : 
  unused argument (filename = paste(plot.n, ".las", sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no argument `filename` in `writeLAS()`. The signature of `writeLAS()` is

```
writeLAS(las, file)
```